# is there a style reset for email clients?

Tags: css, email, html-email, email-client

I design my emails with the general styling rules outlined elsewhere on the web (i.e. Campaign Montior's CSS guide http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and apply only inline styles (I find this more reliable than placing them in the `<head>` section as some clients ignore `<style>`).

Does anyone know if there is a reliable way to effectively reset styles in most major email clients (Outlook 2007 and up, Gmail, Thunderbird, etc)? Something to cover at least the major desktop and mobile clients (http://emailclientmarketshare.com/). Ideally a solution that can be easily applied retroactively to existing HTML email templates would be great.

I am thinking along the lines of what we would use for the web like Eric Meyer's reset.css 
(http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or likewise. Of course we cannot import external CSS rules as we would a regular web page.

Comment: `<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;"></body>` will do the job

Comment: Thanks - that's great for layout and padding but I also want to address fonts, text-decoration and type size.

Comment: You could take `reset.css` and apply all the rules manually using inline `style` attributes.

Comment: @rwcorbett You need to make it all inline

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [HTML Email Boilerplate](https://github.com/seanpowell/Email-Boilerplate) is probably the closest thing you'll find. It's well commented and resets as much as is possible with html emails.

Comment: Nice, didn't know this existed!

Comment: Thanks - I have seen this in the wild before but now I have a definite reason to try it out. AFAIK this is our best solution until mail clients advance past XHTML 1.0 specs.

Comment: Which is not happening any time soon! Outlook is still too popular and doesn't update like the web clients. I can see people still running Microsoft Word powered Outlook versions for another 10+ years...